# Modulo doesn't work

Tags: java, modulo

I know this will seem like a really stupid question, but I just don't get why this isn't working. This:

```
 System.out.println(5 % .10);
```

And it's returning:

```
0.09999999999999973
```

I really have NO IDEA. I'm just learning Java, and I'm pretty good with C#, so I tried with C# to. C# seemed to return the same thing also.

Comment: What is modulus between floats anyway?

Comment: what do you think it should return....

Comment: @Shahzeb he's probably expecting 0 since 0.1 divides 5.

Comment: Modulus is not broken. It is a safe bet however that you have a misunderstanding related to both modulus and floating-point representations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others explained, this is due to inaccuracies caused by floating point precision.

You should use [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), in this case the [remainder method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#remainder%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) for precise arithmetic involving decimals.

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(5);
BigDecimal divisor = new BigDecimal("0.1");
BigDecimal result = number.remainder(divisor);
System.out.println(result); // 0
```

Answer (score 8):

This is due to floating-point precision. `0.10` cannot be represented exactly in binary. Therefore the result is not exactly `0.10` and is hence not modded down to `0`.

This will work with `0.25` because `0.25` **can** be represented exactly in binary.

EDIT:

In general, any number that can be expressed as a fraction with a power-of-two in the denominator can be expressed exactly in IEEE floating-point. (provided it doesn't over/underflow)

Comment: Than how would I go about getting the modulus of .10? Just multiply 5 by 100 and .10 by 100?

Comment: You can multiply 5 by 10 and mod by 1. Then divide your result by 10.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing floating point arithmetic. 0.1 has no exact representation as a float.

Comment: Not really positive what you mean, but it seems to work with other floats. If I do "System.out.println(5 % .25);" it will return 0. Thanks :)

Comment: He means exactly what he said. 0.1 cannot be represented in a IEEE-754 floating point. This is a classic computer science problem.

Comment: 0.25 can be represented because it is a power of 2 (2 ^ -2).

Comment: @sh042067: and that's because 0.25 is 1/4 which can be represented exactly on a digital computer.  Google about digital representation of floating point numbers. This is not a Java problem but a digital computer problem.

Answer (score 1):

Java (like most programming languages except COBOL) is making computations in the binary systems. I think 0.10 has such a unlucky binary representation that the result of your computation looks like this. I think it is best to avoid computing modulus of double or float and stick to integer or long to get better results.

Answer (score 1):

The binary representation for 0.1 is

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.1));
```

prints

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

When you print 0.1, you get a small amount of rounding which hides this error.

When you perform a calculation you have to use BigDecimal or round the result or transform the calculation to minimise error.

```
5 % 0.1
(5 / 0.1 % 1) * 0.1
50 % 1 / 10
```

In terms of double you can do

```
double d = 5;
double mod0_1 = d * 10 % 1 / 10;
double rounded = Math.round(mod0_1 * 1e12)/1e12; // round to 12 places.
```

Note: the result can still have a slight error, but it will be small enough that when you print it, you won't see it.